# Groovy addAll makes a list of lists

Tags: list, groovy

this might not be the best question but I am curious about what might be going on.

I have this piece of code in groovy

```
def markets = []
for (int i = 0; i < marketIds.size(); i += 200) {
    int from = i
    int to = (i + 200) > marketIds.size() ? marketIds.size() : (i + 200)
    markets.addAll(service.getMarketCatalog(args...))
}

markets
```

`service.getMarketCatalog()` returns a list of objects/maps (it's a call to 3rd part API that returns a list of some objects defined in their API. We get them as maps).

For some reason the result of this method is markets being a list of lists. 
So if the for loop runs 3 times and the API responds each time with a list, the list is added to the markets as an object.

Anyone have any ideas why? Maybe I have to define that the result is a list (i.e. `service.getMarketCatalog(args...) as List`) otherwise it is treated as an object and just gets added as an object to the list?

Comment: What does `getMarketCatalog` return exactly?  Do you have an example that we could try?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by my own test...

```
Object x() { return [1, 2] }
def y = []
y.addAll(x())
y.addAll(x())
println y

Result: [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

... no matter what the return type of `service.getMarketCatalog()` is, even if it's just Object, if the value is truly a List or other Collection, then addAll has the expected behavior. I get a warning in the IDE, but Groovy evidently tries casting the Object to a Collection at runtime and succeeds.

Thus I can only conclude that `service.getMarketCatalog()` is not actually returning a single-level list as you believe it is. It must be a list of lists, itself. You'll have to investigate whether that's truly the case. If it is, then of course you can spread the top-level list to addAll each of the sublists: `markets.addAll(*service.getMarketCatalog(args...))`